# Modal not rendering correctly in IE

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

The modal's text is rendered correctly, however the background is rendered only within the range of the screen size, when you scroll it's transparent.

I have noticed that the background is rendered only when some action happens like click on a button on that modal or even when i open the Developer Tools.

This works as expected in other browsers though.

Here is the modal container's css

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
overflow: auto;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 1000;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
```

And the modal itself

```
background-color: ${colors.white};
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 50px;
text-align: left;
cursor: initial;
```

Any ideas what may be the case with IE's rendering?

Comment: We are not able to get an idea about the cause for the issue with only CSS code. I suggest you try to provide an example that we can try to run within the IE browser for reproducing this issue. Let us know, which version of the IE browser you are using for this test? It can help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to sort this out. 
Inside this modal I am actually rendering another div (which has different composition of text and actions in different pages) that inherits this css:

```
background-color: ${colors.white};
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 50px;
text-align: left;
cursor: initial;
```

But apparently when you scroll down and as the new content loads the style does not apply. After adding once again `background-color: ${colors.white};` to the div rendered inside the modal it's all looking nice.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT thanks for the advice, helping other community members is the core of stackoverflow! :)